Calculating Largest Lyapunov Exponent Using nolds Library
Attempted to first use nolds to calculate LLE using my own data, which didn't work even after I made sure the data was float format, one dimensional, etc. Then I tried to generate an array and attempt to calculate LLE using nolds, which still didn't work. Wondering why the function wont accept the input. Wondering if anyone has any experience with nolds and knows why there's an issue.
(https://i.sstatic.net/7A6YmgLe.png)
I already tried making sure my numpy and scipy are compatible. Made sure all of the data is a one dimensional array and all float datatypes.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

It looks like mf is a complex number, so you couldn't apply ceil to 1.0/mf. The following code gives exactly the same error for the last line, even though the imaginary part is zero.
import numpy as np
print( int( np.ceil(1.0/0.3) ) )
print( int( np.ceil(1.0/(0.3+0j)) ) )

Output:
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\c++\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print( int( np.ceil(1.0/(0.3+0j)) ) )
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ufunc 'ceil' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

EDIT
I had a look at the source code (https://github.com/CSchoel/nolds/blob/main/nolds/measures.py). In this instance it does a discrete Fourier transform on your float data to create a complex array f, which eventually propagates into the type of mf. Your particular, perfectly legitimate, function call would do the following (I've trimmed down the code):
import numpy as np
data = np.array( [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ] )
data = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.float64)
n = len(data)
f = np.fft.rfft(data, n * 2 - 1)
print(f)

mf = np.fft.rfftfreq(n * 2 - 1) * f**2
mf = np.sum(mf[1:]) / np.sum(f[1:]**2)
print(mf)

min_tsep = int(np.ceil(1.0 / mf))

Output:
[15.        +0.j         -3.64542968-9.41420081j  0.35844071+3.68236373j
  0.        -3.46410162j  0.28698898+2.70425969j]
(0.15640320149333495+0.023036086643746814j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\c++\test1.py", line 12, in <module>
    min_tsep = int(np.ceil(1.0 / mf))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ufunc 'ceil' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''


Update: I uninstalled the most recent version and used an older verison of the nolds library (0.3.2) and the calculation worked fine. Thanks @lastchance

You might want to report the problem to the author of the code - it seems to be a clear bug.
